# Regex to match a custom ID format

Tags: regex

I need to check if a string has the following format:

- The length must be at least one
- The first character and last character must be alpha-numeric
- Any characters between the first and last character can be anything except white space.

This is my current attempt:

```
/^([a-z0-9]+[\S]+)?[a-z0-9]+$/ig
```

I am new to regex. It seems to work, but does it fully satisfy the requirements above? Is there anything else I need to think about?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, a one character string is a valid format, but because it is both the first and last character, it must be alpha-numeric

Comment: Well, I can't find a major flaw with this pattern. Just remove `g` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why your requirements are satisfied :

- The length must be at least one :

  The end of your regex isn't optional and contains the `[a-z0-9]+` tokens which must match at least one alphanumeric character. To check this with complex regexs I would suggest removing every token that is modified by `?`, `*`, `{0,}`, `{,n}` or `{0,n}`, then removing alternations which are left with an empty alternative. If there still are tokens in the regex, it must match at least one character.
- The first character and last character must be alpha-numeric :

  Either the first character is matched by the optional group or by what follows. Both groups start with at least an occurence of `[a-z0-9]` which satisfies the condition. You correctly use anchors which assert that this condition does apply to the full string rather than to a subsequence.
- Any characters between the first and last character can be anything except white space.

  Your regex doesn't accept any whitespace character, it only accepts characters of `[a-z0-9\S]` which doesn't contain any whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
\b\w([.^\S]*)\w*\b
```

Answer (score 1):

you need change first and last symbol matching
`/^[a-z0-9]\S+?[a-z0-9]$/ig`

in this expression `[a-z0-9]` - one alpha-numeric symbol
`\S+?` any non white space symbol